# Html Helpers giving wrong value when given a certain name

Tags: model, asp.net-mvc-5, html-helper, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have a very weird thing going on in my MVC application. I'm rendering a partial view into a bootstrap popup. The controller action looks like this:

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult GetModalForm(int id)
    {
        var vm = CreateViewModel(id)
        return PartialView("MyPartialView", vm);
    }
```

This seems to work fine, the view model has two fields in it:

```
 public class MyViewModel
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int MemberId {get ; set;}
}
```

So far so good, when I put a break point in the Controller action, the id and MemberId fields are set correctly.

Now here's where things get wacky, I have the following lines in my partial view (for testing the issue):

```
@using ()
{
    @Html.TextBox("id", Model.id)
    @Html.TextBox("something", Model.id)
    <input type='submit'/>
}
```

When this renders, the 1st line gives me a text box with a value equal to the MemberId field, the 2nd line gives me a value equal to the id field. I don't really understand how these two lines can be giving me different values for the same field. What's weird is why is the second line reading the MemberId field?

Has anyone seen anything like this before, or have any ideas what might be causing it? I'm reaching my wit's end.

Thanks in advance for any help.

**UPDATE:**

To help explain what is happening further: If my view model properties are id=x and MemberId=y. Then the following line:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.id)
```

Will render as:

```
<input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="y"/>
```

Comment: What do you mean _giving me different values for the same field_ The first one is binding to a property named `id` and the second one is binding to a property named `something` but your overriding its value with the value of property `id` (an awful practice) Show the actual html your generating.

Comment: The above code would give me:

    <input type="text" id="id", name="id" value="-It put's the member id here-"/>
    <input type="text" id="something", name="something" value="-It put's the id here-"/>

Comment: Not possible, unless the values already been added to `ModelState`. You have either added a parameter for `MyViewModel` in the GET method, or your returning the view from a POST method, and your trying to set the value of the properties before returning the view without clearing `ModelState`. Show your controller methods.

Comment: I did show my controller method. The problem was the action parameter id was equivalent to the view model property MemberId and was taking precedence over the view model property id when setting the model state. Changing the name of the action parameter to memberId resolved the issue.

Comment: I meant the POST method (in case that was the issue). But you didn't show the relevant code anyway (which was the `CreateViewModel()` method where I assume you were setting `model.MemberId = id`)

Comment: I meant the POST method (in case that was the issue). But you didn't show the relevant code anyway (which was the `CreateViewModel()` method where I assume you were setting `model.MemberId = id`)

Comment: No I wasn't setting model.MemberId = id.  I said that when I pout a break point in the controller, the id and MemberId fields were being set correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your action accepts a parameter `id`. That means there's a value in `Request["id"]` and that value will go into the `ModelState`. Whatever is in `ModelState` takes precedence over values set on your `Model`. So, your textbox bound to "id" will take the value from `Request["id"]`.

Two things:

1. It's always better to use the `*For` helpers, since these allow you to bind to your model properties in a strongly-type way.

   ```
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.id)
   ```
2. Whatever action parameters you have, should *not* have equivalently named properties on your view model, *unless* they actually should be the same thing and hold the same values. In other words, if the parameter `id` actually corresponds to `MemberId`, then you should either have no `id` property on your model, or you should rename you action parameter to `memberId`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Yes, I know number 1, that's why I put "for testing the issue" in brackets. I tried seeing what the @Html.TextBox gave to try and isolate the issue and I get what I've explained in the original question.
The line @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.id) is correctly binding to the id property, but it's being rendered with the the memberId value.
As for number 2, the action parameter "id" is equivalent to the view model property "id" in this case.

Comment: Scratch that, I actually looked at the code and the action parameter is referring to the view model property MemberId. I changed the name of the action parameter to MemberId and presto, all is good. So thank-you for your help.